# How to Show attributes of two different beans in one jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts, javabeans

In a small Struts application (not using any data base) I have a `login.jsp` and `register.jsp`.
Once the Login is successful it is redirected to `success.jsp`.
Once the Registration is successful it is redirected to the same `success.jsp`.

Now, once I login I want to display the login name of the person who logged in and after registration I want to show the name of the person who registered. As I am using the same `success.jsp`, how will I display them?

I am using `<jsp:usebean>`, `<jsp:setProperty>`, `<jsp:getProperty>` tags to get the value of the attribute.

Comment: Please read tutorials on HttpSession http://marakana.com/blog/examples/java-jsp-login-system-example.html and http://www.jsptut.com/Sessions.jsp

Comment: Thank you for the links Suresh. But i couldnt get any solution for my problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether bean is initialized, if not so don't use that and use other, for eg for registration only that bean will be init, not login one.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution!

Alog with Loginform bean and Registerform bean, I took another Bean Suppose UserBean and provided setter and getter methods for the LoginName in that bean and i inherited that bean in my Login and register bean.

In Success jsp 
I took a form object of UserBean and wrote the following logic

UserForm form=null;
form=null!=request.getAttribute("LoginForm")
          ?(UserForm)request.getAttribute(LoginForm)
          :(UserForm)request.getAttribute("RegisterForm");